# curveBumpX returns undefined

Tags: d3.js, d3-dag

I'm trying to use curveBumpX/curveBumpY but it returns as undefined.

I don't see it's marked as deprecated and it appears in the autocomplete.

Any idea why?

I'm using d3-dag ver: 0.11.1

I'm trying to create a curved connection between edges

Answer (score 0):

You need d3 7.4.4 and then its availalbe